# How to fix Laravel's routing error with HttpException?

Tags: php, laravel

Am using zizaco entruest rbac and
these are my web routes causing error

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user-management', 'middleware' => ['permission:admin']], function() {

    Route::get('/users', function(){
        return "sds";
    });

});
```

When i try navigating to

```
http://localhost:8000/user-management/users
```

am getting an error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException
No message
```

Where could i be wrong

I have commented all other routes and found this to be the culprit

I have setup my rbac as explained

```
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
```

Comment: Try it without middleware.

Comment: without middleware it works am adding the middleware as explained https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Did you add 'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class, to routeMiddleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php?

Comment: yes already added and even restarted artisan

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC instead of Zizaco to handle Role Base Access Control. It has the same functionalities and no bugs at all.

Comment: ill check it as well

Comment: Try without the trailing slash: `Route::get('users', ...`

Comment: may you post your middleware code here..

Comment: it's your middleware mistake.I tried this code with my own middleware and it worked correctly.

Comment: THe middleware is a package from https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Provide the entire failed information, please.

Comment: can you share the http status code of response?

Comment: which http code do u receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `auth middleware` as well as it checks permission for an auth user within `permission middleware`. You can fix it by just putting `auth middleware` and then try logging in, now you can navigate to `users` url.

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'user-management', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'permission:admin']], function() {

    Route::get('/users', function(){
       return "sds";
    });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks i see where i was going wrng i was using the permission even for unauthenticated users doing it this way solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

You should create a `403.blade.php` template view under `resources/views/errors` directory.
Your application's exception handler do not find the exception status code associated view, so it return the exception directly.

Comment: thats an amazing idea il try and let you know

Comment: nopw all errors are caught by the blade, but doesnt solve the actual problem of the error caused by the middleware, Thanks for the insight though helped in another area

Answer (score 0):

To help you with this we need more information.

- Is this the only route in your application?
- Did you authenticate the user before trying to access /user-manag... ?
- What's inside your app/Http/Kernel.php file? Did you add permission middleware?

Not sure what kind of http code are you receiving ([is it a 403](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/e4aad072a9b1bac68c3127b953bab4206e6af888/src/Entrust/Middleware/EntrustPermission.php#L44)? or a 500?).

Things you can do that might help:

1. Enable debug mode (change your .env (or config/app.php) DEBUG to "true")
2. Check your laravel.log file (storage/logs/laravel.log)
3. Install laravel-debugbar. This package can give you better insight about what's happening in your app.  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: there are other routes, but when troubleshooting the problem i did comment on all others and left this one which brings the error

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up the middleware. It says the following:

```
if ($this->auth->guest() || !$request->user()->can($permissions)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

This means that it crashes without a message if you aren't authenticated or you cannot do something because you don't have permission.

You could try to `dd()` something in here before the abort. Just to see if it reaches this. If it does check this page in the Laravel documentation about `abort()` and custom error pages: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#http-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

apparently your code looks fine. I guess you are having some problem in your middleware its not allowing you to pass through.
you have used permission:admin so i guess you should log in as admin and then it will be working fine.